# How to remove timeout limit in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a get request to a website which is very slow. I am trying to get requests but before the website loads, the requests module gives me a timeout error. How can I stop requests from giving me the timeout error and keep on trying until the website gives some response?

Please help.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts)?

Comment: Yes, I guess you need the whole documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `timeout=None` per [the documentation here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts).

For example: `requests.get("https://example.com", timeout=None, …)`